# r data.table use row n-1 value to calculate row n value

Tags: r, data.table

I want to use a row n-1 value to calculate something in row n. The code below does what I want but is really slow with a large data set because of all the copying of the data table going on. I've tried various experiments with shift, [-1L] in i, and other things suggested in similar posts. Is there an alternate to the `for` loop that would take advantage of data table?

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(GDP = c(12622, 13087, 14772, 17156, 19536, 21979, 24428, 26777, 28990, 31007), 
                 elas = c(.42, .45, .23, .25, .27, .30, .31, .20, .19, .15))

cons.start = 7.2
DT[, cons := 0]
DT[1, cons := cons.start]
DT[,GDP.lag1 := data.table::shift(GDP, type = "lag")]
DT[,temp.inc := elas * (GDP - GDP.lag1)/(GDP + GDP.lag1)]
for(i in 2:nrow(DT)) {
  DT$cons[i] <- DT$cons[i-1] * (1 + DT$temp.inc[i])  / (1 - DT$temp.inc[i])
}
```

Comment: That's a cumulative product, like `DT[-1, cons := DT$cons[1]*cumprod((1+temp.inc)/(1-temp.inc))]` or similar.